# Laravel: Successful login redirects to the login page due to auth middleware on even when correct credentials provided

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, routes, middleware

I am creating an application for a pre-existing web application with pre-designed schema. This application will use the `admins` table to authenticate users (only admins can access this application). I cannot use `users` table because it has data of the clients of the application and do not necessarily need authentication because the application is used by admins only.

I have created the `User` model with the field `protected $table = 'admins'`. In order to user Laravel's inbuilt authentication libraries, I created required columns in the `admin` table by migrating the required fields for authentication such as `email`, `password` and `remember_token`. My `User` models is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;

    protected $table = "admin";
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

I also have a route as follows:

```
    Route::get('/dashboard' , 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard.index')->middleware('auth');
```

The default `LoginController` redirects to route `/dashboard` when user is successfully authenticated. But there seems to be some problem with the `auth` middleware which does not seem to authenticate the currently logged in user to enter into `/dashboard`.

Also, I want to tell you that I have made no changes to the `config/auth` file in the guards key as the `User` model points to the `admins` table which has all the necessary fields for authentication which is as follows:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
             'driver' => 'session',
             'provider' => 'users',
         ],

         'api' => [
             'driver' => 'token',
             'provider' => 'users',
         ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
         'users' => [
              'driver' => 'eloquent',
              'model' => App\User::class,
         ],
     ],
```

Now each time that I tried to access the `/dashboard` or any other routes with `auth middleware`, the application sends me to the login page. Since the login page will redirect to the dashboard ( which has `auth middleware`), I get redirected to the login page even when I pass correct credentials i.e. `email and password`.

**Note that** I checked the authentication of provided credentials through debugging and the controller successfully authenticated the provided credentials.(I checked this in the `authenticated()` method in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait that Laravel's `LoginController` users. Notify me if this method is not appropriate to check whether the user was authenticated).

Is there some problem with the `auth middleware` or do I need to modify my `guards configuration` in the `auth config file` ?

Or, do I need to remigrate my migration files for admin table?

Please suggest best alternatives. Thank you..

Comment: I have same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you change the  provider on the 'web' guard to 'admins' since the default is 'users'

Comment: This is unnecessary because the web guard has User model as its provider and the User model has admins as its database table set.